# Applying SharePoint theme using CSOM - The request uses too many resources

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, csom, resources

I have an Azure web job that provisions SharePoint Online sites and during the process it applies an out of the box SharePoint theme. The theme is determined by the process, but can be "Orange" or "Sea Monster" (both OOTB SharePoint themes).

Previously all sites were created successfully, but in the last month the web job now fails when it tries to apply the Sea Monster theme with the following error message:

> Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: The request uses too many resources.

The error message implies that the more complicated theme is over the 2MB size limit for a CSOM operations request, but the web job was definitely able to apply the theme previously as I have been running the job for months.

Has my web job been throttled? If so, why was it not throttled previously? Also, it seems unlikely that the "Sea Monster" theme is over 2MB in size, is there any way to check this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, were you using the SP.Web.ApplyTheme method to apply the theme? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj251358.aspx.

And if so, have you been able to resolve it? I'm running into a similar issue calling that method in JSOM from an Add-In Web.

Comment: Yes, we used web.ApplyTheme to set the theme. We didn't resolve it as such, but switched to a template with a simpler theme (no background image) to avoid the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is too late and you already fixed, nor what are your environment details, but it might be you find a tip that helps you to fix the too many resources issue here.

[Fixing timeout exception on CSOM based site collection creation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2015/12/02/fixing-timeout-exception-on-csom-based-site-collection-creation/)